# Java word game with GUI. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I created a simple Java GUI word game.

It starts of with a head, and the user tries to guess the word. If it is right, the system prints out correct. If it is wrong, it will print out "wrong" and draw a body. The top text box is the hidden word (not really hidden) and the bottom is where you insert your guess.

What is wrong with this program is, the body is not painted after the user guess the wrong word.

The first class:

```
package hangman;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class NewClass extends JPanel {

int lineA, lineB, lineC, LineD;
int guess;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    //head
    g.drawOval(110, 10, 25, 25);
    g.drawLine(lineA, lineB, lineC, LineD);// (ideal) 125, 40, 120, 100

}

public void newPaint(int a, int b, int c, int d) {


    lineA = a;
    lineB = b;
    lineC = c;
    LineD = d;

 super.revalidate();

}
}
```

The second class:
      package hangman;

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class NewClass1 extends JFrame {

private JTextField answerBox, hiddenAnswer;
NewClass nc = new NewClass();

public NewClass1() {

    hiddenAnswer = new JTextField();

    hiddenAnswer.setText("hat");// this is the word for the hangman

    answerBox = new JTextField("put you answer in here");
    answerBox.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {


            if (event.getActionCommand().equals(hiddenAnswer.getText())) {
                System.out.println("you got it right");
            } else {
                System.out.println("sorry you got it wrong");


                nc.newPaint(125, 120, 40, 100);

            }
        }
    });
    add(BorderLayout.NORTH, hiddenAnswer);

    add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, answerBox);
 }
 }
```

entry point

```
    NewClass1 ncc = new NewClass1();

    NewClass nc = new NewClass();
    ncc.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,nc);
    ncc.setVisible(true);
    ncc.setSize(300,300);
    ncc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


}
}
```

Comment: You should consider more meaningful names for classes than `NewClass` and `NewClass1`. And if you defined a method like `newPaint(…)` how about using that method instead writing directly to the fields of your object?

Answer (score 1):

Use your `newPaint` API in the event, instead of directly setting the fields of `NewClass`.

```
if (event.getActionCommand().equals(hiddenAnswer.getText())) 
{
     System.out.println("you got it right");
} 
else 
{
     System.out.println("sorry you got it wrong");
     nc.newPaint(125, 120, 40, 100);
}
```

**Edit:** In the `NewClass1`, replace the `repaint()` with `revalidate()`. [Here's the reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392722/how-to-repaint-a-jpanel-after-have-drawn-on-it).

**Edit2:** In your case, it is best that you **don't** create the `NewClass` panel outside of `NewClass1`. In the `NewClass1` constructor you can do this:

```
nc = new NewClass();
add(BorderLayout.CENTER, nc);
```

before you add the `hiddenAnswer`, and then you can remove the `NewClass` from the entry point.

The thing is, you weren't working on the instance of `NewClass` that you've created in the entry point, you were working with a random new `NewClass`.

Comment: I did not get any more errors. But now, it still does not paint the body.

Comment: @pur3extrme Call `revalidate()` instead of `repaint()` in your `NewClass`.

Comment: sorry but the program is still not fixed with all of the corrections.

Comment: @pur3extrme Please edit your question and post the program entry-point, i.e. your `main` method.

Comment: Ok, please check it now.