# paintComponent() doesn't get called

Tags: java, swing

My `paintComponent()` won't get called.

I have Googled a little, and haven't found an answer that I could use. At first, I didn't have the `frame.getContentPane().add(this)`, and thought that the answer was to insert that, but neither that worked. I hope someone can help me out.

Here you have a little snippet of my code:

```
package engine;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Frame extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private GameEngine engine;
    private Game game;

    public Frame(GameEngine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
        frame.getContentPane().add(this);
    }

    public void updateGame(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.drawString("" + game.getClockDate(), 1920 - 100, 20);
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

I'm calling it from here, in another class:

```
public void loop() {
    if (this.ingame) {
        game.loop();
        frame.updateGame(game);
        frame.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `loop` called? You should also reset creating a `JFrame` inside your `Frame`'s constructor, this kind of side effect is dangerous, bad design and difficult to manage, it's not your `Frame`s responsibility to decide how it's used ;)

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Try calling super() as the first line of your constructor so that your JPanel initializes correctly.

```
public Frame(GameEngine engine) {
    super();
    this.engine = engine;
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
    frame.getContentPane().add(this);
}
```

Also call the @Override annotation for getting your code clear.

```
@Override    
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.drawString("" + game.getClockDate(), 1920 - 100, 20);
        System.out.println("test");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post what context you are trying to paint this Frame object (where, when, and how you are using the paint method in your Frame object).

General diagnostic resources:

[1. Inheritance Hierarchy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html)

[2. This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544549/how-does-paintcomponent-work) has a very good position on why not to use `paintComponent()` and to use `repaint()` instead. I have never been put into a situation where I have needed to forge a path with `paintComponent()`, however I have been in a position to use `repaint()` several times.

Comment: i have added it now

Comment: [Instead of calling `repaint()` consider trying `revalidate()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392722/how-to-repaint-a-jpanel-after-have-drawn-on-it).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `repaint` in the game loop, but `repaint` does not guarantee that window will be repainted and therefore `paintComponent` may not be called. You should instead use `paintImmediately`.

```
paintImmediately(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
```

Comment: From the docs *"In most cases it's more efficient to call repaint"* :P - Not say that this isn't a possibility, but I'd prefer to know what `paintComponent` isn't been called properly in the first place, as `repaint` should (eventually (milliseconds)) trigger and new paint cycle